# Install postgis 2.3.0 for postgres 9.5.3.1 on Win7 in unattended mode?

Tags: postgis, installation

Does any one know how to do this?

The PostgreSQL install is easy and works like a charm but I'm trying to also install PostGIS in unattended mode with no user interaction, and it keeps popping up the gui and asking me to agree with the terms.

Comment: Example for postgres http://pginstaller.projects.pgfoundry.org/silent.html you should be able to use the same method to include postgis functions

Comment: Thanks, but the procedure for postgres versus postgis was slightly different. See the answer below by @LR1234567.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The installer uses NSIS - http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#silent

Try this:

```
postgis-bundle-pg95x64-setup-2.3.0-1.exe /S /D="C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5"
```

Comment: This did the trick, saved me a lot of time. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

The current installer for PostGIS 2.4 **doesn't like quotes**, and it will silently do nothing if you include them.

This does nothing:

```
postgis-bundle-pg10x64-setup-2.4.4-1 /S /D="C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10"
```

And this works:

```
postgis-bundle-pg10x64-setup-2.4.4-1 /S /D=C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10
```

The installer is Nullsoft's NSIS, documentation for it is here:
https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Docs/Chapter3.html#installerusage